Proving $\lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+} \int_{\alpha \epsilon}^{\beta\epsilon} \frac{f(x)}{x}dx=f(0) \ln(\beta / \alpha)$
I am trying to understand the proof of Frullani integral theorem and have come to a part of the proof where the following claim is made:

$$\int_{\alpha \epsilon}^{\beta\epsilon} \frac{f(x)}{x}dx=\int_{\alpha \epsilon}^{\beta\epsilon} \frac{f(0)}{x}dx=f(0) \ln(\beta / \alpha) \quad\text{as} \quad \epsilon \to 0$$

If I assume the continuity of $f$, I an use the MVT for integrals to conclude that $$\int_{\alpha \epsilon}^{\beta\epsilon} \frac{f(x)}{x}dx=f(\xi_{\epsilon})\ln(\beta/\alpha)\to f(0) \ln(\beta /\alpha)$$ but I am only given the continuity of $f$ at $0$, so I don't think this is legal. I would appreciate any hints on how to tackle this.

If $f$ isn't continuous at $0$, $f$ can be defined with arbitrary $f(0)$, so how could its appearance in the answer be correct?

@J.G. It was a typo. I apologise. I meant I only have continuity at 0

Given $\eta > 0$, we can find $\delta > 0$ such that
$$f(0) - \eta < f(x) < f(0) + \eta$$
whenever $|x| < \delta$. Therefore for sufficiently small $\epsilon > 0$:
$$\int \limits_{\alpha \epsilon}^{\beta \epsilon} \frac{f(0)-\eta}{x} \, \mathrm{d}x < \int \limits_{\alpha \epsilon}^{\beta \epsilon} \frac{f(x)}{x} \, \mathrm{d}x < \int \limits_{\alpha \epsilon}^{\beta \epsilon} \frac{f(0)+\eta}{x} \, \mathrm{d}x$$
and so
$$\big( f(0) - \eta \big) \ln \frac{\beta}{\alpha} < \int \limits_{\alpha \epsilon}^{\beta \epsilon} \frac{f(x)}{x} \, \mathrm{d}x < \big( f(0) + \eta \big) \ln \frac{\beta}{\alpha}.$$
